# if condición = 1 entonces deberia ocultar los de = 0 , pero no va

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin, if, while

Tengo un condicional if que deberia mostrar los productos con condición = 1 excepto los de valor = 0. Pero sigue mostrado todos los productos. En la base de datos está con TYNINT(1). He probado cambiar el campo 'condición' tipo BOOLEAN con true y false pero nada , quizás debe ser un fallo de lógica, de alguna llave  pero no sé verlo. Alguien sabe resolverlo?

```html
 <div class="gallery col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

 <?php
  $sql_prod = "SELECT * FROM productos ORDER BY id DESC"; 
                $resultado_prod = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql_prod);
  if(mysqli_num_rows($resultado_prod)){
  while ($row_prod = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_prod)){ 

  $condicion = $row_prod['condicion'];

  if($condicion == 1){
 ?>

 <div >
            CONTENIDO HTML
        </div>

 <?php }
           
    }

 }else{ ?>
            
 <div class="col-sm-12"><h2>No hay productos en esta categoría</h2></div>
              
 <?php }
 ?>
```

Comment: Haz `var_dump($condicion)` para ver lo que hay por dentro de esa variable.

Comment: Tal vez sea igual que con PDO, y tienes que acceder al arreglo así: `$row_prod[0]['condicion']`

Comment: Tu código no contiene ningún error... puedes hacer también una captura de pantalla de tu base de datos?

Comment: `if ($condicion == 1)` esta dentro del `while` y el `else` esta quedando con la otra condición `if(mysqli_num_rows($resultado_prod)){` ¿Así como lo tienes es correcto?

Comment: El vardump arroja string(1) "1"  string(1) "1"  string(1) "1" ...
Ya no sale el contenido con condicion = 0. 
Gracias por las respuestas

Comment: Entonces ya no ocurre el problema? Era un problema de sintaxis a lo mejor? Hay que buscar la manera de marcar esta pregunta como solucionada o borrarla, para que no se meta gente a tratar de responderla